# Could not create tool plugin with ptype: gxp_zoomtolay

Tags: boundless-suite

I am new in OpenGeo Suite Library and SDK client. I am following the tutorial for the tools:

http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/sdkintro/viewer/featureinfo.html
http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/sdkintro/viewer/zoomtolayerextent.html

But I get this error when I try to refresh my application:

> Error: Could not create tool plugin with ptype: gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo
>   src/ext/ext-all.js Line 7

My code is not long as I just started the tutorial and I havent modified much.
What I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

```
/**
 * Add all your dependencies here.
 *
 * @require widgets/Viewer.js
 * @require plugins/LayerTree.js
 * @require plugins/OLSource.js
 * @require plugins/OSMSource.js
 * @require plugins/WMSCSource.js
 * @require plugins/ZoomToExtent.js
 * @require plugins/NavigationHistory.js
 * @require plugins/Zoom.js
 * @require plugins/AddLayers.js
 * @require plugins/RemoveLayer.js
 * @require RowExpander.js 
 * @require overrides/override-ext-ajax.js
 * @require plugins/ZoomToLayerExtent.js
 * @require plugins/WMSGetFeatureInfo.js
 **/

var app = new gxp.Viewer({
    proxy: "<PROXY_URL>",
    portalConfig: {
        layout: "border",
        region: "center",        
        // by configuring items here, we don't need to configure portalItems
        // and save a wrapping container
        items: [{
            id: "centerpanel",
            xtype: "panel",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "center",
            border: false,
            items: ["mymap"]
        }, {
            id: "westpanel",
            xtype: "container",
            layout: "fit",
            region: "west",
            width: 200
        }],
        bbar: {id: "mybbar"}
    },

    // configuration of all tool plugins for this application
    tools: [{
        ptype: "gxp_layertree",
        outputConfig: {
            id: "tree",
            border: true,
            tbar: [] // we will add buttons to "tree.bbar" later
        },
        outputTarget: "westpanel"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_addlayers",
        actionTarget: "tree.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_removelayer",
        actionTarget: ["tree.tbar", "tree.contextMenu"]
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_zoomtoextent",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_zoom",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    }, {
        ptype: "gxp_navigationhistory",
        actionTarget: "map.tbar"
    },{
        ptype: "gxp_wmsgetfeatureinfo",
        outputConfig: {
        width: 400
        },
        actionTarget: {
            target: "map.tbar",
            index: 1
        }
     },{
        ptype: "gxp_zoomtolayerextent",
        actionTarget: ["tree.tbar", "tree.contextMenu"]
    }],

    // layer sources
    sources: {
        local: {
            ptype: "gxp_wmscsource",
            url: "/geoserver/wms",
            version: "1.1.1"
        },
        osm: {
        ptype: "gxp_osmsource"
        }
    },

    // map and layers
    map: {
        id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above
        title: "Map",
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        center: [-10764594.758211, 4523072.3184791],
        zoom: 3,
        layers: [{
            source: "osm",
            name: "mapnik",
            group: "background"
        }, {
            source: "local",
            name: "usa:states",
            selected: true
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: "gx_zoomslider",
            vertical: true,
            height: 100
        }]
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I figured out my problem. In case it is useful for someone else. Everytime a new dependency is added, the application will need to be restarted to see the changes. In the terminal, type CTRL+C to stop the SDK and then run the debug command again.